# Prefix lenses for a type

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have the following data declared:

```
data Something = Something
  { self              :: String
  , id                :: String
  , description       :: Maybe String
  , name              :: String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Something

makeLensesFor
  [ ("self", "somethingSelf")
  , ("id", "somethingId")
  , ("description", "somethingDescription")
  , ("name", "somethingName")
  ]
  ''Something
```

Is it possible to automate the lenses creation as the naming convention is following really simple rules.

After a peek at the source code, I can see there's a LensRules instance, called abbreviatedFields, but, sadly, using it with `makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''Something` generates no lenses at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the source code: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/src/Control.Lens.TH.html#abbreviatedFields

Comment: I [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Object_(category_theory)) to calling this thing [`Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Category.html#t:Category).

Comment: Objection sustained. :)

Comment: Note also that `id` clashes with `Prelude.id` and also (categorically!) with `Control.Category.id`. I'd go with something like `ident` if I were you.

Comment: Well, I'm using Data.Aeson and it generates its parsers based on field names, so I'm kind of obligated to use these identifiers. Of course, there's a good chance that Aeson provides me with a way to rename identifiers, but still that won't help me with my main question. :)